# Display in the suggested edit review when an answer edit was made by the question asker

Tags: feature-request

Could the suggested edit review screen have a note/flag/image/[vuvuzela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vuvuzela) to identify when an edit to an answer was made by the original question asker.

This would make it easier to identify instances when the edit can be rejected with 'attempt to reply'.

These attempt to reply edit are fairly easy to spot, but I've had three of these this morning and at least one was not so easy to catch.

---

Edit: 
This feature would have helped [this review in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21304469). [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21304667) was also a bit tricky.

Comment: Shouldn't the edit itself be enough to identify attempts to reply? Can you please look in your review history and link one of these cases where the edit itself wasn't clear and the requested highlight would have helped?

Comment: @Tom Please see my edit

Comment: I do not understand exactly what value would this provide. Do you think these edits would be easier to reject or easier to accept?

Comment: @yivi I think it would make them easier to identify and reject. There is already a "banner" mesage that pops down saying "this question has been flagged as spam", so it could just be another one of those: "this edit was suggested by the question asker". It would give the reviewer more information on which to base their decision.

Comment: But why would these cases be treated differently if the question asker is the one making the edit? You already know is someone different than the author.

Comment: If the asker is editing an answer it increases the chance of it being an attempt to reply. It _should_ be obvious from the edit, but I think my examples show it isn't always.